# How to debug issues in docker image when there is no error

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, docker-image, docker-for-windows

I am building a ASP.NET web API application running on .net framework 4.5. Here is my docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY TestWebAPI/*.csproj ./TestWebAPI/
COPY TestWebAPI/*.config ./TestWebAPI/
RUN nuget restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY TestWebAPI/. ./TestWebAPI/
WORKDIR /app/TestWebAPI
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release


FROM microsoft/iis:10.0.14393.206

SHELL ["powershell"]

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY --from=build /app/TestWebAPI/. ./

RUN Remove-Website -Name 'Default Web Site'
RUN New-Website -Name 'TestWebApi' -Port 80 \
    -PhysicalPath 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot' -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5'
EXPOSE 80

CMD Write-Host IIS Started... ; \
    while ($true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600 }
```

Then i Run following commands:

```
 docker image build --tag v7 --file .\Dockerfile .
 docker container run --detach --publish 80 v7
docker ps to get the port number
```

When I go to specific port, the site does not load. There was no error while building containers. How can I find the issue (obviously its my docker file)

Comment: Have you runned the command `docker logs <cointainer_id>`? Any relevant info?

Comment: @CassioFariasMachado: Let me give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The command that is executed when running the container is

```
CMD Write-Host IIS Started... ; \
    while ($true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600 }
```

This obviously does not start the website as the steps executed with the RUN command are only executed during build time of the image.

I guess you meant to also execute the two steps executed within the build phase of the container with the RUN command. This can by achieved by either chaining them within the CMD step of the Dockerfile or by creating a small script wrapping these commands and executing it.